# Compare 2 Arrays and if one item of one array is the same exit from loop

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

Another one question.

I have create a custom form in outlook to assign tasks in users.
All is good until now but i want to do more advance. I have the field To to add recipient and a button Send to send email notification. When someone add a recipient and click in send button send the email notification and save the assigners in a TextBox Multiline separated with vbCrlf.
My problem is that i don't want someone to add a recipient that allready exist in Assigners (TextBox Multiline). I try to compare the two fields without sucess. In this case i have add another one TextBox that get the value of To field when added to compare with the other field that i have it for Assigners.
Find below my code

```
       Sub add_Click()
        Set objPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Assign Task")
        Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set objduedate = objPage.Controls("duedate")
        Set objowner = objPage.Controls("owner")
        Set objpriority = objPage.Controls("priority")
        Set objprogress = objPage.Controls("progress")
        Set objstartdate = objPage.Controls("startdate")
        Set objpercentcomplete = objPage.Controls("percentcomplete")
        Set objassignee= objPage.Controls("assignee")
        Set objtest= objPage.Controls("TextBox5")

        Dim isFound 

         strText = objassignee.Value
         arrLines = Split(strText, vbCrLf)
         strTest=objtest.Value
         arrtest = Split(strTest, vbCrLf)

         For b=0 to UBound(arrLines)step 1
          isFound = False
           For i=0 to UBound(arrtest)step 1
            if arrtest(i)=arrLines(b) then 
             msgbox "True"
             isFound=True
           Exit For
         end if
       Next

       if arrtest(i)<>arrLines(b) then 
         msgbox "False"
        isFound=False
       Exit For 
      end if
     Next
    End Sub
```

Any suggestion how can compare the Recipient if it's the same with any of the assigners that i have it in the Assigner field TextBox Multiline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling duplicates by a double for/next loop, you can let a [dictionary object](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13992) do it for you. This is demonstration code, you have to convert it to your specific situation.

```
option explicit
dim assignees, recipients, assigner, recipient
dim dictAssignees

' Original lists of assigners and recipients:
assignees = "Joe;John;Josh;Jack"
recipients = "Paul;Ringo;John;George"

' Add the assigners to a dictionary
Set dictAssignees = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
for each assigner in split(assignees, ";")
    ' The value is only set to True because we have to set it to just something.
    ' You can set the value to any other boolean, string or object (numbers are converted to strings)
    dictAssignees.Item(assigner) = True
next

' Add recipients that are not already in the assignees list to the dictionary
for each recipient in split(recipients, ";")
    ' You can build duplicate logic like this:
    if dictAssignees.exists(recipient) then
        msgbox "The recipient " & recipient & " was already present in the assignees list"
    end if
    ' Or just add the items, the dictionary object will handle duplicates
    dictAssignees.Item(recipient) = True
next

' Show the list of assignees
msgbox "Assignees: " & join(dictAssignees.Keys, ";")

' Output: "Joe;John;Josh;Jack;Paul;Ringo;George"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's very easy to use in a complex requirement as the comparison between arrays or strings.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the Recipient.Address properties of the two recipients.

Comment: If a user add more than one recipient how can compare the first recipient with the Assigner field TextBox Multiline and after the 2nd recipient with the Assigner field TextBox Multiline ?

Comment: Use TaskItem.Recipients collection to enumerate the recipients.